# Insertion of multiple embedded data in MongoDB by Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb-java, morphia

Want to insert multiple embedded in mongoDB by using Morphia.I want to insert data like this:

{ "_id" : ObjectId("55f67a57128699b6e5eab719"), "className" : "com.emecpoc.entity.User", "smeId" : "SME1", "creator" : "admin@souvik.emec.co.in", "dateOfUsage"
: "2015-06-29", 
"UsageDetail" : [{ "timeOfUsage" : "11:52:49.0", "usageType" : "Storage Consumed", "length" : "81326" },
{ "timeOfUsage" : "12:12:55.0", "usageType" : "Storage Consumed", "length" : "115593" } ,
{ "timeOfUsage" : "12:12:55.0", "usageType" : "Storage Consumed", "length" : "5383663" },
{ "timeOfUsage" : "11:52:49.0", "usageType" : "Storage Consumed", "length" : "46310" } ]
}

Beans are like this:

```
 @Entity("User")
    public class User {
        @Id
        ObjectId id;
        String smeId,creator,dateOfUsage;
        Timestamp created;
    @Embedded("UsageDetail")
        //List<UsageDetail> usageDetail;
        UsageDetail usageDetail;
//getter and setter methods
}
```

This is the embedded bean class:

```
 public class UsageDetail {
      private String timeOfUsage;
      private String usageType;
      private String length;
    //getter and setter methods
    }
```

But I am getting result like this:

```
    { "_id" : ObjectId("55f67a57128699b6e5eab71c"), "className" : "com.emecpoc.entity.User", "smeId" : "SME1", "creator" : "admin@souvik.emec.co.in", "dateOfUsage"
    : "2015-06-29", "UsageDetail" : { "timeOfUsage" : "11:52:49.0", "usageType" : "Storage Consumed", "length" : "46310" } }

If I remove @Id from User bean then results 4 data entry like this:
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55f67a57128699b6e5eab719"), "className" : "com.emecpoc.entity.User", "smeId" : "SME1", "creator" : "admin@souvik.emec.co.in", "dateOfUsage"
: "2015-06-29", "UsageDetail" : { "timeOfUsage" : "11:52:49.0", "usageType" : "Storage Consumed", "length" : "81326" } }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("55f67a57128699b6e5eab71a"), "className" : "com.emecpoc.entity.User", "smeId" : "SME1", "creator" : "admin@souvik.emec.co.in", "dateOfUsage"
: "2015-06-29", "UsageDetail" : { "timeOfUsage" : "12:12:55.0", "usageType" : "Storage Consumed", "length" : "115593" } }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("55f67a57128699b6e5eab71b"), "className" : "com.emecpoc.entity.User", "smeId" : "SME1", "creator" : "admin@souvik.emec.co.in", "dateOfUsage"
: "2015-06-29", "UsageDetail" : { "timeOfUsage" : "12:12:55.0", "usageType" : "Storage Consumed", "length" : "5383663" } }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("55f67a57128699b6e5eab71c"), "className" : "com.emecpoc.entity.User", "smeId" : "SME1", "creator" : "admin@souvik.emec.co.in", "dateOfUsage"
: "2015-06-29", "UsageDetail" : { "timeOfUsage" : "11:52:49.0", "usageType" : "Storage Consumed", "length" : "46310" } }
```

So please guide me how to insert multiple data in embedded part  only.

Answer (score 1):

Make `usageDetail` a `List` again and then just add as many references to `UsageDetail` as you need.  By removing the ID from `User` and saving again, you're telling the driver/Morphia that it's a wholly new object to be saved so you end up with multiple documents in the user collection.